# htaccess redirect non-image resources

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website somedomain.com, and a CDN set up to the subdomain www.somedomain.com. (I would have liked to make it cdn.somedomain.com, but did not have the option).

The CDN is effectively a dumb mirror. I want to use it to deliver image assets, but NOT pages.

These .htaccess rule are doing the right job of redirecting image requests to the CDN. (I don't really care about restricting by file extension.)

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.somedomain\.com\/images\/$1" [R=301,L]`

How can I extend this same .htaccess file to ensure that non-asset requests like www.somedomain.com/something/or/other is redirected to somedomain.com/something/or/other (no www)?

Comment: does non-assets include pages and everything else?

Comment: Yes, pages, javascript and css. I'm confident I can add the latter resources to the CDN if I need to.

Comment: You have separate .htaccess files for www and no-www or same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this. Use two rules. And you don't need to do escapes in the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ http://www.somedomain.com/images/$1 [R=301,L]

#if it's not the image folder redirect to main domain without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.somedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somedomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```